# Why is the JSON stringification of a subclassed array an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, subclass, stringify

```js
/* StackOverflow needs a console API */ console.log = function(x) { document.write(x + "<br />"); };

B = function() {}
B.prototype = Array.prototype;

var a = new Array();
var b = new B();
a[0] = 1;
b[0] = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

JSON stringifies the subclass as an object ( `{ "0": 1 }` ) instead of as an array ( `[1]` )`

Is there any way to modify this behaviour?

EDIT

I'm using (non-negotiably) ES5. I've simplified the example slightly. In reality, the subclassing is set up through a function `inherit()` which does this:

```
var inherit = function(base, derived) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = base.prototype;
    derived.prototype = new F();
    derived.prototype.constructor = derived;
};
```

Comment: …because you didn't [subclass `Array` properly](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/), your constructor returns an object. Use an ES6-compliant environment and  `class` syntax.

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? A simple solution would be overwriting `toJSON`, but I guess you actually don't really want to subclass `Array`.

Comment: @Bergi see edits. I'm doing this because I just needed to add a tiny bit of behaviour to an array which is being passed around in many places.

Comment: Extend the Array prototype then if you must. You can't subclass an Array, only in ES6 as Bergi has said. Or use an array like object.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Maybe you want to extend (decorate) that particular array instance then? Btw, if you're using ES5, you should be using `Object.create` instead of this `new F` trick.

Comment: Huh. So much complexity and subtlety to inheritance in JS that I still don't grok. I think in my case, adding `toJSON()` is the simplest.

Comment: Arrays are a unique case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot inherit from array. As soon as you create a constructor function, the instances of it will be objects. When you want the functionality of an array, rather create an array and add the methods on it you want. This can be done with a function:

```
function createExtendedArray () {
    var a = [];

    a.method1 = function() {};

    return a;
}
```

Comment: The strange thing is that they behave like arrays in some contexts: `console.log(b)` uses array notation.

Comment: This is maybe because of Array.isArray(b) is false? b instanceof Array is bizarrely true. I think this is JS magic ;)

Comment: and I suspect the behaviour of console.log is instance specific?